# trying to find iframe that wraps email Id field

Tags: java, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I want to switch my webdriver to iframe before entering email id in the email id box. I am not able to locate the iframe that surrounds the email id box.

How do i locate iframe in order to make below code work?

Below is the java webdriver code,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class HandlingIframes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.navigate().to("http://www.firstcry.com/");

        Thread.sleep(3000);     

        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='amt']/div[2]"))); //This locator is not working.

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']")).sendKeys("happita@gmail.com");

        Thread.sleep(4000);

    }

}
```

Comment: Which iframe are you referring to? There are multiple iframes in the webpage? Can you highlight the iframe you are trying to access with the html code?

Comment: The html would help anyone to be able to answer you. Or, simpler, just right click on the page and select page source and search for the iframe

Comment: Yep. that was the problem. there were multiple iframes in the page and I wasn't sure which iframe to use. But then I went to the page source and tried an iframe id that looked most right and passed it to frame(). Its working fine now. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I went to the page source and found the id of the iframe and used it. Below code is working fine now.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class HandlingIframes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.navigate().to("http://www.firstcry.com/");

        Thread.sleep(3000);     

        driver.switchTo().frame("iframe_Login");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']")).sendKeys("happita@gmail.com");

        Thread.sleep(4000);

    }

}
```